# How can i access a field inside a doc inside a collection?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I keep trying to access a field inside the message collection. But for some reason it's not working when i try it use data['number']. But when i try to put in my number directly, its working. Why is that ??

To clarify, in the message collections. Documents are stored with docId being phone numbers. So, here me using data['number']
i am trying to find the document with my phone number.

```
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Future<bool> validateUser() async {
    try {
      var querySnapshot = await db
          .collection("clients")
          .doc("kzQXhk79OcPXiG9wXTTkhuPH6iu1") // Replace with dynamic client ID
          .collection("guests")
          .get();

      print("Successfully completed");

      for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
        print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()} ');
        Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        var messageSnapshot = await db.collection("message").doc(data['number']).get(); //issue here
        if (messageSnapshot.exists) {
          print("Document data: ${messageSnapshot.data()}");
        }

      }
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error completing: $e");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

when i try
`var messageSnapshot = await db.collection("message").doc("41233xx123xx2").get();`  
it works
but this doesnt
`var messageSnapshot = await db.collection("message").doc(data['number']).get();`

when printing `data['number'].runtimeType`  i get a string

I am so confused and annoyed to why it isnt working haha. What am i missing?

I tried converting `data['number'].tostring` and tried other methods but still nothing works!

Comment: You should edit the question to show the actual contents of all the documents in use here.  We can't see any of that, so we don't know what's actually in `data` or what could be going wrong here.  There should be enough information in your question that anyone can use the reproduce the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using .trim() at the end of the data['number']
Turns out data['number'] was the correct phone number. Just had a space at the end for some reason